# Is there any way to pass parameters to quartz cron job?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler, quartz

I have a cron job in quartz (spring boot application).
I have created beans for scheduler, trigger, cron job , and all other beans.
The purpose of job is to run based on specified cron expression. But for each fresh execution of the job, I want to pass some data specific to that job, to the job detail object.
But currently, when i try to pass such data in JobDetailFactory bean, it is only created once(for the first time), and for all further executions of the job, same stale data is being passed. I want to pass fresh new data each time job is executed.
How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use some kind of callback? So something like this in your `Job`:

```
@Resource
private MyJobJobdataProvider dataProvider;

public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
    JobData data = dataProvider.getData();
    /// configure job with the data before actual exection ...
}
```

where `MyJobJobdataProvider` would be any component that provides this data:

```
@Component
public MyJobJobdataProvider {
    public Data getData() {
        //...
    }
    public void setData(Data data) {
        //...
    }
}
```

So instead trying to set new data let the job query for it before each execution.

Answer (score 0):

This is what the job data map can be used for. Please check [JobExecutionContext.getMergedJobDataMap()](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.3.0/org/quartz/JobExecutionContext.html#getMergedJobDataMap--) method and the [JobDataMap](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.3.0/org/quartz/JobDataMap.html) API.

If you want to modify the job data map parameters programmatically at runtime, you have two options:

1. Obtain the Scheduler reference, e.g. in [JobExecutionContext.getScheduler()](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.3.0/org/quartz/JobExecutionContext.html#getScheduler--) method and modify the desired job data map parameters of any job. Unfortunately, the Quartz API provides no method to update a job detail so you have to delete a job detail and add a new one if you wish to modify an existing job.
2. Let your job(s) implement the [StatefulJob](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.3.0/org/quartz/StatefulJob.html) interface. This makes Quartz automatically persist the job data map when the job execution finishes. This can be used, for example, to resume processing of data from a specific point after the previous job execution finished at that point etc.

Comment: Following on your first point, my understanding is that it would edit the job data map of the single job that has been created. What i want is that for each new execution of the job, there needs to be some specific data related to that execution only. The reason i want data associated to that particular job instance is that, if that job fails and tries to recover itself later, then it should get its relevant data back.